# ASP.NET gridview - how to add dynamically populated dropdown to dynamically bound gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, dynamic-programming

I looked around for answer about my problem already, but I gig not find anything conclusive. I Want to to the following:
I have an asp.net form with a GridView which is not bound to a data source which hence does not have pre-defined columns. I populate the gridview with data from an SQL Server dynamically:

```
gvComponentLocks.DataSource = getComponentsAndLocks(worksPermitID);
//Note getComponentsAndLocks encapsulates the database query and returns a DataTable
gvComponentLocks.DataBind();
```

Now I want to have a DropDownList in one specific column of the GridView. This DropDownList shall be populated with values dynamically (here I think the ...Item.Add is the appropriate approach).
My biggest problem is how to create the DropDownLists in the cells without being able to define them statically as asp:TemplateField in the web page's markup?

Another way to answer my question would be how to populate a statically defined GridView (with statically defined DropDownList control) dynamically with data from a data source - without the need to bind the GridView statically to a DataSource.

Comment: its actually pretty easy. try datasource control within your html and bind it there. just give the datasourceId to your dropdownlist and its done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the DropDownList dynamically in the `RowDataBound` event of the GridView.

```
protected void gvComponentLocks_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //create a new dropdownlsit
        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();

        //bind the source and define the values
        ddl.DataSource = getComponentsAndLocks(worksPermitID);
        ddl.DataTextField = "columnA";
        ddl.DataValueField = "columnB";
        ddl.DataBind();

        //add the dropdownlist to the gridview in column 1
        e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(ddl);
    }
}
```

The only thing you also have to do is to place the DataBBinding of the GridView outside the `IsPostBack` check. Otherwise you'll lose the DropDowns after a PostBack.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming GridView (with statically defined DropDownList control)

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

In side

```
  protected void gvComponentLocks_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
```

do something like...

```
DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
 DropDownList1.DataSource=SomeDropDownList1ItemCollection
 DropDownList1.Bind();
```

Alternatively return from a ListItemCollection, preferably...

```
 gvComponentLocks.Items.AddRange(LoadList().Cast<ListItem>().ToArray());
```

where

```
public ListItemCollection LoadList()
            {

    ListItemCollection Items = new ListItemCollection();
                Items.Add(new ListItem("Choose from list...", ""));
                Items.Add(new ListItem("Text","Value")
```

Dynamic DropDownList:
Put a PlaceHolder Control in the Template in the Grid. Create a DropDownList control with appropriate ids in the code behind and add to the PlaceHolder control.

```
 DropDownList DropDownList1= new DropDownList();
DropDownList1.ID=... 
etc
YourPlaceHolderControl.Controls.Add(DropDownList1)
```

You will have to build back this dynamic DropDownList on postback and repopulate it.

Comment: Thanks Nothing, still I wouldn't know how to do the data binding of data from the server to this statically defined GV. Do you have a hint for me how to do that? I tried this "static layout" approach yesterday, but somehow didn't manage to display the data in the GV defined at design time.